# Dark Souls 3 controller not working

Tags: steam, controllers, dark-souls-3, windows-11

On starting Dark souls 3 (steam/win11/razer blade 17) only the mouse and keyboard would work despite having an xbox series controller wirelessly connected. The xbox button prompts were there but the controller did nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by:

Going to Big picture mode > settings (cog icon) > controller settings > untick all except "guide button focuses steam"

Start the game and it works flawlessly.